# How to run through the objects, that are inside an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run through an array, then through the objects, then calc the age and return it.

```
const people = [
    {
        name: "Carly",
        yearOfBirth: 1942,
        yearOfDeath: 1970,
    },
    {
        name: "Ray",
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011,
    },
    {
        name: "Jane",
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941,
    },
]
//console.log(people[0].name);

const findTheOldest = function(people) {
    
    
}

function getAge(...people) {
let age = 0;
    for (let element of people) {
       console.table(element);
        }
       
   }
getAge(people);
```

I've read all the articles, blogs, YT tutorials etc. They have examples of accessing one but not both like this.

Comment: You can use a `for-loop` or use the `Arrays.reduce` method to iterate over the array and calculate the age of each person in the array.

Answer (score 1):

from what i understand you want to get the oldest person this would be one way

```
const people = [
    {
        name: "Carly",
        yearOfBirth: 1942,
        yearOfDeath: 1970,
    },
    {
        name: "Ray",
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011,
    },
    {
        name: "Jane",
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941,
    },
]

people.map((person,i) => {

    people[i].age = person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth;

});

function getOldstPerson(people){
    let oldestPerson = people[0];
    people.map((person) => {
        if(person.age > oldestPerson.age){
            oldestPerson = person;
        }
    });
    return oldestPerson;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make object and use forEach to add key, value of it

```js
const people = [
    {
        name: "Carly",
        yearOfBirth: 1942,
        yearOfDeath: 1970,
    },
    {
        name: "Ray",
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011,
    },
    {
        name: "Jane",
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941,
    },
]

function findOldest(){
  let oldest = {}
   people.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc = acc > item.yearOfDeath - item.yearOfBirth ? acc :        item.yearOfDeath - item.yearOfBirth
          oldest = {name:item.name,age:acc}
      return acc
   }, 0);
   return oldest
}

function getAges(people){
 let ages = {}
  people.forEach(person => {
    ages[person.name] =person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth 
  })
  
  return ages
}

const peopleAges = getAges(people)
const oldestPerson = findOldest(people)
console.log('peopleAges : ',peopleAges)
console.log('oldestPerson : ', oldestPerson)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to find the oldest person. You can get it by updating your `findTheOldest` function as below

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Carly',
    yearOfBirth: 1942,
    yearOfDeath: 1970,
  },
  {
    name: 'Ray',
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941,
  },
];

const findTheOldest = (people) => {
  const defaultMinAge = 0;
  return people.reduce(
    (accumulator, person) => {
      const age = person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth;
      if (age > accumulator.age) {
        return { name: person.name, age };
      }
      return accumulator;
    },
    { age: defaultMinAge }
  );
};

const oldestPerson = findTheOldest(people);
console.log('The oldest person is ', oldestPerson);
```